# Plotting TimeDeltas in Pandas

Tags: datetime, numpy, matplotlib, pandas, timedelta

I'm trying to plot timedeltas on the x-axis, but am seeing strange behaviour. With the following code, I would expect two curved plots:

```
dates = [datetime.datetime(2013,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=x**2) for x in range(1000)]
deltas = [datetime.timedelta(seconds=x**2) for x in range(1000)]
values = range(1000)
foo = DataFrame.from_dict({'dates': dates, 'deltas': deltas, 'vals': values})
foo.plot(x='dates', y='vals')
foo.plot(x='deltas', y='vals')
```

but in fact the second plot comes out as a straight line as in that case the x-axis is rescale. Is this a bug or am I just doing it wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not properly supported by matplotlib ATM, so see this issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8711)

workaround is easy enough, just set the index to the formatted (string version) and it will work.